# my website refuses to serve .png files

Tags: apache, png

When moving a site from a staging environment to a production environment, .png image files are not being shown.  When going to the image directly, firefox reports:

**The image (image-path) cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.**

I've checked mime.types in my apache config, and it contains a line for

image/png            png

does anyone know what could be causing this?  I've never encountered this before.

Comment: Does this just happen to PNGs or any other image files too?

Comment: Did you try opening the image (not remotely, locally)?
Is the software trying to output image on runtime? ( like PHP or Java)

Comment: What's the operating system on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check .htaccess file url rewrite or any permission/restrictions etc.
2. **upload any png image and try to open it browser using direct path to ur png file. such as http://localhost/images/test.png (if it works fine, it means your apache process your png successfully fully)**
3. check if you have created any symbolic link your images directory in your previous server(host).
4. check your directory permissions.
5. **clear your browser cache.**
6. check your appach virtual host file httd.conf in your preivous host. may be previous there has been created some alias or something like that. 
   httpd.conf:
   ...

   > ```
   >  <VirtualHost www.mydomain.com:80>
   >              ServerAdmin hostmaster@www.mydomain.com
   >              DocumentRoot /home/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs
   >              ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/www/www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
   >              ServerName www.mydomain.com
   >              Alias /images/ /home/www/www.mydomain.com/images/
   >              Alias /pictures/ /home/www/www.mydomain.com/upload/
   >              Alias /errors/ /home/www/www.mydomain.com/errors/
   >              Alias /catalog/ /home/www/www.mydomain.com/catalog/
   >              ErrorLog /home/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/error_log
   >              CustomLog /home/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/access_log
   >              ScriptLog /home/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/script_log
   >              ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
   >              ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
   >              ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
   >      </VirtualHost>
   > ```

let me know if any of this works or not

Answer (score 6):

i solved the same issue checking for capital letters in the file name. all of my .png files had capital .PNG suffixes. made everything lower case and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem two weeks into trying to fix it.

On ubuntu linux the problem was linked to sendfile. A kernel based os function that was not working properly with apache2. 
 [Just added "EnableSendfile off" to my apache2.conf and images now load OK.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10009776&postcount=5)

I hope that helps.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1385583

Answer (score 2):

If your image is a real one: maybe the image was broken during the FTP transfer (incomplete or bad/non binary transfer). Download it back from the server and have a look at it.

If your image is virtual or script generated: post the code, so we can have a look at it! This often happens with PHP if you have some chars before the `<?php` opening tag for example.

Comment: thank you you were correct.

Filezilla was not in Auto, but rather in ASCII mode.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a lot of things unfortunately:

- Check the file permissions on the file, and ensure that apache can read them
- Is this an 'actual' file, or is it coming from a DB or similar?  If it's coming from a DB or Code investigate the actual string to be sure that content is being generated properly.  If there are errors, they would ruin the output of the image
- The file could actually be corrupt (try a re-upload)

Answer (score 0):

as configuration file comments say

"EnableSendfile **must be turned off when serving from networked-mounted filesystems** or if support for these functions is otherwise broken on your system. "

which was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you transfer the images in binary mode when transferring through FTP

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old, but if someone is looking for a solution to problems with displaying .png files with 'img' tags, I spent quite a while searching with no results. On a whim I checked the image and it had an alpha channel. I removed the alpha channel and eureka, it worked. Just another thing to check if you have a similar problem.